# How to setup a web proxy page where I can log into google docs and other blockes sites?

Tags: proxy, redirection

I live in a place where http://docs.google.com is blocked. Is there any way I can access it through a web proxy (a page where I can type the address)? I have an EC2 machine, and I tried using phpProxy to do that, but it doesnt work with docs.google.com . My proxy supports https, so that is not the issue.

any suggestions?

I cannot use tunnels. It must be a browser-based proxy.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I create SSH to tunnel HTTP through server like it was proxy?](http://serverfault.com/questions/78351/can-i-create-ssh-to-tunnel-http-through-server-like-it-was-proxy)

Comment: I updated the question, I cannot use ssh tunnels. I must use a browser-based proxy.

Comment: How are you maintaining your EC2 instance if you can't use SSH? The ssh `-D` dynamic tunnel is not like standard ssh tunnels - it establishes a SOCKS-compatible proxy from your localhost through to the remote server.

Comment: To clarify, the solution specified in the duplicate *is* a "browser-based proxy".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not setup squid or a similar web proxy on your ec2 instance, then its a matter of configuring your browser to connect to that proxy, but if you cant use ssh tunnels how come you can manage your ec2 instance as that generally requires ssh?

Answer (score 1):

If you've got a box with SSH access, my favorite way is to use SSH tunnelling.

```
ssh -D 127.0.0.1:10080 user@host
```

That open up a SOCKS proxy on local port 10080

You can use something like FoxyProxy then to access that for specific URLs in Firefox, or simply set it as a SOCKS proxy in your favorite browser.

This way your traffic is always encrypted to your remote host also whether or not you're accessing an SSL endpoint. Anyone analyzing traffic will just see ssh traffic.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question, I cannot use ssh tunnels. I must use a browser-based proxy.